# getting wrong Data when converting Dictionary to Data

Tags: swift

I'm converting a `[String: Any]` to `Data` using:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [ "a": "abc",
                            "b": true,
                            "c": 1000 ]
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json)
```

When printing the `data` object it get:

> bplist00Ô"#X$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top ©U$nullÓ
>   WNS.keysZNS.objectsV$class£
>   £QbQaQc    SabcèÒZ$classnameX$classes\NSDictionary¢
>   !\NSDictionaryXNSObject_NSKeyedArchiverÑ$%Troot#-27AGNVahlnprvxz|~¥²µÂËÝàå&ç

Is using `NSKeyedArchiver` the wrong way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: That's a binary property list – you did not tell *what* you want to achieve.

Comment: What you have is Dictionary<String, Any> and nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `NSKeyedArchiver` is not used to get JSON data. Instead use `JSONSerialization.data`.

Example:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

UPDATE:

In swift 4 you can either use `JSONEncoder`. For example

```
let obj: [String: Encodable] = [ "a": "abc",
                            "b": true,
                            "c": 1000 ]

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(obj)
}catch {

}
```

Comment: I haven't checked that. Will have look and update my answer.

Comment: @MartinR I'm getting for JSONEncoder an error - Fatal error: Dictionary<String, Any> does not conform to Encodable because Any does not conform to Encodable.

Comment: @sahara108 SWift4 version not working getting an error -  Fatal error: Dictionary<String, Any> does not conform to Encodable because Any does not conform to Encodable

Comment: @ilan can you try to use [String: Encodeable] instead of [String: Any]?

Comment: not working, 
Fatal error: Dictionary<String, Encodable> does not conform to Encodable because Encodable does not conform to itself. You must use a concrete type to encode or decode.